# Where in the rabbinic writings are there examples of the word "Elul" that mean or imply "harvest" and/or "search"?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, rosh-chodesh-new-month, maseches-rosh-hashana, elul, kiddush-hachodesh

Where in the rabbinic writings are there examples of the word "Elul" that mean or imply "harvest" and/or "search"?
Which word in Aramaic means "search" that uses the similar spelling of "Elul"?

My question came from reading the following:

> The name of the month Elul ... originated from the Akkadian word for
> "harvest".
>
> The word "Elul" is similar to the root of the verb "search" in
> Aramaic.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elul

Comment: Wow, it was +1 and someone just downvoted this, during this 40 day season that leads up to Yom Kippur. May Hashem bless you, whoever you are. I definitely do not want to offend you, as I would hate asking for your forgiveness.

Answer (score 8):

For the first one: there's an Aramaic term עללתא, meaning "crop" or "harvest" (see [Talmud, Nedarim 55a](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.55a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and [Targum Onkelos to Vayikra 25:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Onkelos_Leviticus.25.3?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)). Could be that the Akkadian cognate, if there is one, had an aleph instead of an ayin. (In fact, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkadian_language#Descent_from_Proto-Semitic), Akkadian lacked an ayin sound.)

For the second: the Aramaic word for "spy" (one who searches out information) contains the root אלל. (For example, when Yosef accuses his brothers of being spies and they defend themselves, [Onkelos (Bereishis 42:9 passim)](https://www.sefaria.org/Onkelos_Genesis.42.9?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) translates מרגלים variously as מאללין, אלילי, מאלילי.)

Comment: do you have an Onkelos example for the Aramaic term עללתא?

Comment: @ninamag Added one.